# UWP MediaPlayerElement - how to loop/repeat mp4

Tags: c#, uwp, mp4

I have an mp4 that I need to repeat in a page.

How can this be achieved?

```
<MediaPlayerElement
    Grid.Row="0"
    Background="White"
    Source="{x:Bind MovieSource}"
    Width="900" 
    AutoPlay="True" >

</MediaPlayerElement>
```

I tried to use a storyboard but found out that `MediaTimeline` is not available in UWP.

Can't find a working alternative...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [MediaPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement.mediaplayer#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_MediaPlayerElement_MediaPlayer) property of the MediaPlayerElement class has an [IsLoopingEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer.isloopingenabled#Windows_Media_Playback_MediaPlayer_IsLoopingEnabled) property.