# Problem with MediaPlayerElement looping videos UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am developing a wildlife related application and want to keep looping a short video of certain animals.

I am using MediaPlayerElement to play the video. With some research, I've found out that the MediaPlayerElement has a function called IsLoopingEnabled for looping media. But when I try implementing it, a sytax error is shown telling me

> 'MediaPlayerElement' does not contain a definition for 'IsLoopingEnabled' and no accessible method 'IsLoopingEnabled' accepting a first argument of type 'MediaPlayerElement'could be found (are you missing a using derivative or an assembly reference?)

My XAML code:

```
<MediaPlayerElement x:Name="mediaPlayer"
    Source="ms-appx:///Assets/video.mp4"
    Width="Auto"
    AutoPlay="True"
    Stretch="Fill"
    AreTransportControlsEnabled="False" />
```

In C#

```
mediaPlayer.IsLoopingEnabled=true;
```

[UWP MediaPlayerElement - how to loop/repeat mp4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52128282/uwp-mediaplayerelement-how-to-loop-repeat-mp4) and official documentation show that this function exists. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there. `MediaPlayerElement` has a property called `MediaPlayer` which has `IsLoopingEnabled`. So you need to set it like below.

```cs
mediaPlayer.MediaPlayer.IsLoopingEnabled = true;
```

Comment: @szskdgi I had the same question few months back. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730683/uwp-mediaplayerelement-vs-mediaelement) is where i learnt about the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was stuck in this part for quite some time.